# create event for mouse movement from child to parent in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>text</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Say my mouse is currently hovering `<li>`, I want (using jQuery) an event to trigger when the mouse move away from `<li>` to `<ul>`, and another event to be triggered if the mouse move away from `<il>` to `<body>`. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at event.target: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: Thanks! this led me to event.relatedTarget